# pymongo error on ec2 but working on VM on laptop

Tags: python, pymongo

error code: 
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://********?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 621, in **init**
connect_timeout=timeout)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 463, in parse_uri
nodes = dns_resolver.get_hosts()
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/srv_resolver.py", line 102, in get_hosts
_, nodes = self._get_srv_response_and_hosts(True)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/srv_resolver.py", line 83, in _get_srv_response_and_hosts
results = self._resolve_uri(encapsulate_errors)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/srv_resolver.py", line 79, in _resolve_uri
raise ConfigurationError(str(exc))
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lifetime'

versions: 
python 3
pymongo: 3.10.1

Comment: you may need to install `dsnpython` with `pip install dsnpython --user`

Answer (score 0):

In my case was solution to use older type of URL:

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://:@...

SW:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python 2.7.17 / 2.7.12
- Pymongo 3.11.1
- Google Cloud SDK 319.0.0

Connection from test file directly for os was OK, but same code run from Google SDK dev appserver2 failed.

After change URL generated by cloud.mongodb.com Atlas
in section Cluster -> Connect -> Choose a connection method -> Python - 3.4 or later
It finally (after 4 days searching) started working.